# Setting a different textAppearance for selected and unselected tabs in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-styles, android-design-library

Does anyone know how to go about setting distinct `textAppearance` for selected and unselected tabs in a `TabsLayout`?
The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) only mentions a one-size-fits-all `tabTextAppearance` attributed and only allows setting a different color for the selected tab by means of `tabSelectedTextColor`.
My goal is to use a different font face on the selected tab.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it in `onTabSelected` of `OnTabSelectedListener` interface

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeFace(TYPE_FACE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeFace(TYPE_FACE);
                }
            }
        }
}
```